# Post deleted but it still appears in active tab, is it expected behavior?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, activity-tab

I just found a user spammed 9 answers to own site in specific tag which were link only answers and had marked them as VLQ. They had been deleted as well, but they still appear in active tab (9 of them).

Is this expected behavior or should the post be removed from the active tab once they have been deleted (so that we have a clean active tab)?

The [active tab of specific tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc?sort=active&pageSize=50) I'm talking about.

Comment: What do you mean by "active tabs"? If you mean tabs you have open, then no the deleted post won't disappear until you refresh the page.

Comment: @ChrisF I updated the question, I meant active tab of specific tag.

Comment: When were the answers deleted?  It could be caching.

Comment: @bluefeet, probably they were deleted +- 15 minutes ago.

Comment: Then [caching, it's always caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).